# Eliminating line breaks when using HTML Tables in a Web Application

Tags: html, css

I'm running into an issue with my application/browser prepending line breaks, on top of an HTML table, that is within a display form. I highlighted the space with the line breaks and did an inspect in the web browser. I was able to successfully use

```
div br{
    display: none;
}
```

to eliminate the line breaks, however, this action also removes all other line breaks in other HTML components of the application. My experience with CSS/HTML is very limited, so I'm asking for input, on how the line breaks in the form itself may be removed using CSS, without affecting other HTML components in the application.

[image]

Comment: Just use a more specific selector, such as `form .form-item br {...}`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Terry. If I wanted to get down to very specific so, would it be --> form .form-item form-desc bound-visible br {...} ?

Comment: I am thinking you should avoid a band-aid and fix the issue.  What is creating/appending those `<br>` elements to your document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should fix whatever generates that much `<br>` tags.

But to remove it with CSS inside specific element you should target `<br>` tags inside that element.

So if you wan't to remove `<br>` tags inside `<p class="form-item form-desc bound-visible">` then target it like this in CSS:

```
.form-item br {
  display: none;
}
```

If you want to target element with multiple classes do it like this:

```
.form-item.form-desc.bound-visible br {
  display: none;
}
```

If you have multiple forms and elements with class `form-item` then you could add `id` to your forms and then target just form you need.
Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/py9n7xwe/

Comment: Excellent. Thanks jakob.